# Change visual step size of TProgressBar?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar, delphi-7

I have a form with a TProgressBar set up as follows:

```
myProgressBar.Step := 1;
myProgressBar.Min := 0;
myProgressBar.Max := 60;
myProgressBar.Position := 0;
```

A timer with 1000ms interval is started on form start and every timer tick the progress bar is stepped. After 60s the bar is nearly full (see image, with a debug label showing the time elapsed) but there are only ~19.5 blocks in the bar, not my expected 60. This means that you only see a step about every 3s.

[image: TProgressBar with overly chunky steps]

Is there anything I can do about this? None of the exposed properties in the designer seem to help. I'd be happy to send the control a message if this solved the problem. For example, I use this code elsewhere to change the colour of a progress bar at runtime:

```
SendMessage(pbBin1.Handle, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, clLime);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The progress bar is drawn by the system and you don't get to choose the block size. Instead you could use a smooth progress bar. Set the `Smooth` property to `True`.

Comment: Of course! Not used that property before and it does exactly what I need. As an aside, I note that the `Smooth` property is attached to the Windows message `PBS_SMOOTH`.